# Launching Microsoft Edge browser from a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, windows-10, microsoft-edge

```
var oIE = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
var URLname1 = "http://www.google.com";
var URLname2 = "http://www.bing.com";
var navOpenInBackgroundTab = 0x1000;
oIE.Visible = true;
oIE.Navigate2(URLname1);
oIE.Navigate2(URLname2, navOpenInBackgroundTab);
```

Above is a bit of code in my javascript *file* (launch.js) that launches Internet Explorer with a specific webpage and then opens a new tab in the same browser window using a 2nd URL.

How do you launch the `Microsoft Edge` browser instead of `IE` in Windows 10 using `ActiveXObject()` or another similar method?
I cannot find the `InternetExplorer.Application` equivalent for Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Microsoft Edge no longer supports ActiveX http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/06/a-break-from-the-past-part-2-saying-goodbye-to-activex-vbscript-attachevent/    Where are you lanching the launch.js from?

Comment: Hi Roman.  I'm executing the script .js file from my desktop.  So the javescript code itself is being executed by Window's JavaScript Runtime and not Edge or IE.

Comment: so it's like you're double clicking the .js file from the desktop or does it get executed on Windows startup?

Comment: I'm double clicking, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an instance of the WSH Shell object instead:

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
oShell.Run("cmd.exe /C start microsoft-edge:http://www.microsoft.com");
```

Comment: In my test, when it's executed in Windows, this code fails to open the Edge browser. It only opens a command prompt. Does it work for you?  (I tested it by cutting and pasting into a test.js file and double clicking on it.)

Comment: Update!  Adding /C to the command string got it working. "cmd.exe /C start microsoft-edge:http:// www.microsoft.com"  Now I still need to figure out how to get it open subsequent URLs in new tabs in the same Edge window.  But this is a good start!

Comment: updating my code. please dont forget to vote if it helped

Comment: is your landing page actually a website you maintain? if yes, you can add javascript code that will open up tabs once loaded

Comment: Actually using the Run() method multiple times with different URLs does in fact open new tabs in the same Edge browser window. I should have tested this and not assumed it would open multiple Edge browser windows. Your solution does work for me.  I marked it as accepted.  My only remaining issue is one of elegance.  Which is when opening many URLs at once (40+ URLs in my case) via the script, it has to open and then close 40 temporary command prompt windows. Adding a 2nd parameter of 2 to Run() does at least minimize the cmd windows until they all eventually close on their own.

Comment: 40+ URL's at the same time, you sure you're not writing malicious code?

I'd re approach your site/page's intention and design From a UX perspective.

Answer (score 6):

Windows 10 provides URI schema for lauching Microsoft Egde from any browser. We dont use AcitveXObject at all.

Just include `microsoft-edge` protocol handler before your URL.

How I resolved it

```
function openLinkInIE(url){
  window.open("microsoft-edge:"+ url);
}
```

Comment: Hi, what type is the variable "window"?

Comment: its part of Web Api , check out this link for more info.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open 
@Castaa